# Paypal express really confusing for customers

Tags: checkout, paypal, paypal-express

Paypal express is really confusing how it works.

Most ecommerce sites you see. You click `paypal express` on basket, Fill out your username and password. Then get redirected to a `Thank you for your order` page with order number

However Magento seems to have this extra step to confirm details.
Has anyone any idea on how to skip this section completely?
Go straight from paypal to completing order?

Answer (score 5):

[Then you don't want to use Paypal Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607180/magento-easy-way-to-remove-paypal-express-review-step). Use Paypal Standard. Here's the difference:

> **Paypal Express** only allows the customer to log in to Paypal before having to enter any information on the store's checkout, thus the
>   "Express" in the name. This allows you to re-use common
>   billing/shipping addresses or payment methods. A review step is
>   required in Magento.
>
> **PayPal Payments Standard** takes the customer to PayPal's site AFTER the ENTIRE checkout in order to make payment. Order is "completed" on
>   Paypal.

<sub>Source: http://www.zen-cart.com/content.php?70-whats-the-difference-between-paypal-standard-express-and-pro</sub>

Comment: I get what you are saying. But the express is not done like this on other major retailers. The standard paypal is slow. The express would be brilliant if it wasnt for this extra step

Comment: Express has the option to avoid the review step. To my knowledge this is not possible in Magento. Magento requires the review controller action to be hit for the order to finish completion on Paypal's side.

Answer (score 1):

You may find this Stack Overflow question and the various responses useful:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607180/magento-easy-way-to-remove-paypal-express-review-step/14313748#14313748

Answer (score 0):

Go into the "Advanced Settings" and look for the option "Skip Order Review Step".  Change that to "Yes" instead of "No".